# Modifing Ground plane in eagle PC

Tags: eaglecad

Once I establish a ground plane in Eagle PC, how can I relieve it(remove spots locally)  such as under smd caps in a filter circuit to avoid impedance change.
Andy-KM4TRT

Comment: Have you ticked the box for self generation of thermal reliefs? I don't know eagle hence not really an answer.

Comment: You can use restrict polygons.

Comment: You'll want to draw a cutout polygon. There's a duplicate question on here. Just trying to find it.